# Can sinus infections cause skin problems?

Tags: dermatology, otolaryngology

I have been suffering from nasal septum deviation and I find it difficult to breathe. I've planned a surgery to treat it. I've started developing acne problems on my skin and was wondering if it could be because of previous sinus infections.

Comment: Have you had a related infection?  Without citation I can say off the top of my head that there is some possibility that an infection in sinus can cause an immune activation against a common acne-causing bacteria and your symptoms could be related.  You're in the right place to find out.

Comment: Related: http://health.stackexchange.com/q/1863/1830